# Adding data to jQuery-Flexigrid without ajax-request

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I want to save some unneeded requests and time for displaying a table the first time and so I thought maybe I could set the initial data directly without any ajax-request. I tried it like that:

```
$('#testTable').flexAddData('[formatted json here]');
```

and also that

```
$('#testTable').addData('[formatted json here]');
```

But it hasn't any effect. Can I do that and what is the right syntax?

Comment: Hello daniel, can u please share how does your formatted json look like, actually i am stuck in similar kind of problem where i don not how hot to pass this formatted json.please be kind enough. I have also added the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353271/add-data-to-flexigrid-through-web-service)

Comment: Hi jeev, I wrote a blogpost about that. Maybe it helps you despite it is german. http://blog.ebene7.com/2013/03/12/jquery-flexigrid-ohne-initialen-ajax-request/

Comment: thank u very much Daniel. i appreciate ur help :)this means alot to me :)Do u have any other ideas in which the code doesn't use PHP , just a plain vb.net web-service?

Comment: The PHP code is just for example. I does not matter what language you use. The grid is embedded in a simple HTML-file, the JSON comes from a controller action maybe. You could also use a plain static JSON as data source. I'm not used with vb.net, otherwise I would give you some code sample.

Comment: Thanks Daniel .I found out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the `eval()`?

```
$("#testTable").flexAddData(eval('[formatted json here]'));
```

or try

```
$("#testTable").flexAddData(eval('[formatted json here]')).flexReload();
```

hope this helps

Comment: No, I didn't use it, but it takes also no effect. Maybe anyone has an working example for me!?

Comment: Could you please update your question and put a sample of your JSON data?

Comment: Ok, I found the error. I got the ajax-url in my tableoptions and it loaded and overrides always my data. So it works, but invisible. I changed some settings and now the initial load works without an extra ajaxrequest.

Answer (score 2):

I've also met this problem and spent a lot of time trying to solve it. Solution in my case was pretty simple. You just need to specify dataType : "json" obviously in `flexigrid()` function. Default dataType is XML. So, it don't want to understand JSON:

```
$("#myTable").flexigrid({dataType : "json"});
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement **Anwar** and **user1635430** answers, here is an example JSON code:

```
{
"page": "1",
"total": "9",
"rows": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "cell": [
            "1",
            "text1",
            "user1",
            "date1"
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

The code is done by **Anwar**, I "stole" it from his answer on some other question.